# Python datetime subtraction - wrong results?

Tags: python, datetime

I must be doing something wrong here, any ideas?

```
>>> (datetime.datetime(2008,11,7,10,5,14)-datetime.datetime(2008,11,6,9,30,16)).seconds
2098
```

It should be getting more than that many seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`timedelta.seconds` gives you the `seconds` field of the timedelta. But it also has a `days` field (and a `milliseconds` field).

So you would want something like

```
delta = datetime.datetime(2008,11,7,10,5,14)-datetime.datetime(2008,11,6,9,30,16)
delta.seconds + delta.days*86400
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually returning a timedelta which has a day field also i.e.

`c.seconds = 2098`

but

`c.days = 1`

Answer (score 2):

I wonder that there's still no [total_seconds](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) example.
It works for both python2 and python3. And it's the easiest way to get timedelta total seconds count.

In your case

```
In [5]: (datetime.datetime(2008,11,7,10,5,14)-datetime.datetime(2008,11,6,9,30,1
   ...: 6)).seconds
Out[5]: 2098

In [6]: (datetime.datetime(2008,11,7,10,5,14)-datetime.datetime(2008,11,6,9,30,1
   ...: 6)).total_seconds()
Out[6]: 88498.0
```

Another example:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime
In [2]: d1 = datetime(2018,1,1)
In [3]: d2 = datetime(2018,1,3)
In [4]: td = d2 - d1
In [5]: td.seconds
Out[5]: 0
In [6]: td.days
Out[6]: 2
In [7]: td.total_seconds()
Out[7]: 172800.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`timedelta.seconds` isn't the total number of seconds, it's the remainder in seconds after days have been accounted for.  Using your example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> (datetime.datetime(2008,11,7,10,5,14)-datetime.datetime(2008,11,6,9,30,16))
datetime.timedelta(1, 2098)
```

That `datetime.timedelta(1, 2098)` means that your timedelta is *1 day*, **plus** *2098 seconds*.

What you want is something like:

```
>>> delta = (datetime.datetime(2008,11,7,10,5,14)-datetime.datetime(2008,11,6,9,30,16))
>>> (delta.days * 86400) + delta.seconds
88498
```

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.datetime(2008,11,7,10,5,14)-datetime.datetime(2008,11,6,9,30,16)` returns a `datetime.timedelta` object which has a `days` attribute. The difference that you are calculating is actually 1 day and 2098 seconds.